# how can I change the colour of my text in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm making a witcher themed combat game for a school project, and I cannot figure out how to change the colour of my text.

my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

background = PhotoImage(file = 'background.png')
win_screen_image = PhotoImage(file = 'win_screen.png')
lose_screen_image = PhotoImage(file = 'lose_screen.png')


def introductionCanvas():
    intro_screen = Canvas(root, height = 720, width = 1280)
    intro_screen.create_image(0, 0, image = background, anchor = 'nw')
    intro_screen.pack()
    intro_text = intro_screen.create_text(240, 80, font = 'Calibri 18', text = '     Welcome, Witcher\nPlease Enter Your Name:', )

introductionCanvas()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to use tag_configure, but then I had to change the .create_text to a intro_screen = Text(root, ...), and I couldn't figure out how to add the actual text without getting an error.

Comment: Did you not look at [the documentation for `create_text()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_text.html)?

Comment: couldn't find it on new mexico tech's documentation (the one provided by my teacher

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `fill = 'red'` or what ever color to change it in the same place you change font:

```
intro_text = intro_screen.create_text(240, 80, font = 'Calibri 18', fill = 'red', text = '     Welcome, Witcher\nPlease Enter Your Name:', )
```